# Как добавить файл в память?

Tags: c#

Есть файл, используется другим процессом!
Мне нужно скопировать файл который занят процессом в память, для дальнейшего чтения.

Какие есть варианты?

Нужно использование что-то на подобие:

```
File.Copy("откуда", "куда");
```

File.Copy - справляется с задачей если скопировать в отдельное место на диске, после можно спокойно читать файл, мне же нужно скопировать или загрузить файл в память.

Вариант через `FileStream` сразу отпадает, он не позволяет прочитать файл чтобы добавить его в память, так-как используется другим процессом

Comment: `using (var fs = File.OpenRead("file.txt"))` но зависит от другого процесса, позволяет ли он читать этот файл посторонним или нет.

Comment: @aepot, тоже пробовал, файл не позволяет прочитать, так-как занят другим процессом и не даёт записать данные в память

Comment: Уточните, а текстовым редактором файл открывается когда занят этим процессом?

Comment: `тоже пробовал` Значит вам не открыть этот файл. Приложение, которое заняло этот файл, не позволяет использовать совместный доступ к файлу для чтения. Нужно закрыть приложение, или сделать так, чтобы оно отпустило файл, и только после этот его использовать.

Comment: а если FileShare.Read сделать?

Comment: @SoulOFTrue [File.OpenRead() - GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/File.cs#L260).

Comment: @aepot, верно, мне нужно его сначала копировать в другое место, я думал можно ли скопировать файл в память, допустим как отдельно временной файл и читать его уже внутр, а не напрямую из начального пути.

Comment: @ZidoX копирование - это чтение из одного места и запись в другое. Но если чтение невозможно, то дальше вы уже поняли.

Comment: @aepot, а вот File.Copy работает как тогда? Через него получается скопировать файл уже открытый в другом процессе

Comment: Я не знаю, как. Должно быть никак.